# Make the angular link, database

Tags: angular, hyperlink, bdd

I have trouble making my angular and database link

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')); 
    this.annonceService.findOne(id).subscribe(data => this.annonce=data);
}
```

could you tell me if this looks like a good code

Comment: Not enough information here. Also, please format your code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.